# When uninstalling chrome extension, it calls chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener first and then chrome.management.onUninstalled.addListener

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to call all four methods `onEnabled` `onDisabled` `onUninstalled` `onInstalled` that should fire whenever user perform any of above option. The issue occurs only when user try to uninstall the extension.

Also Note here I am talking about performing operation on others extension.

Could anyone please gives a headsup on this?

Here is the code sample:

```
\\ This should fire when extension is disabled.

chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(function callback(info) {
var appCount = {};
var extList = [];

if (!(info.isApp)) {
    //appCount++;
    appCount = {
        ExtensionName: info.name,
        ExtensionVersion: info.version,
        ExtensionId: info.id,
        ExtensionStatus: info.enabled,
        OfflineEnabled: info.offlineEnabled
    };
    extList.push(appCount);
}
})

\\ This should fire when extension is uninstalled 
\\ either through chrome://extensions/ or from its home page

chrome.management.onUninstalled.addListener(function callback(info) {
var appCount = {};
var extList = [];

 if (!(info.isApp)) {
        //appCount++;
        appCount = {
            ExtensionName: info.name,
            ExtensionVersion: info.version,
            ExtensionId: info.id,
            ExtensionStatus: info.enabled,
            OfflineEnabled: info.offlineEnabled,
        };
        extList.push(appCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not "rather than", but "both events are fired". First it's disabled, then uninstalled.

Comment: Okay... I missed to add ddebugger there. Yes, I can see it calls both. So is this expected behavior?

Comment: Apparently Chrome first disables the extension internally then removes it. This is not documented so it may change in the future (or maybe it was different in the past).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Chrome first disables the extension and then uninstalls it. Which means both of methods fire in case of uninstallation.